# Spark 2.1 on MAPR 5.0

Tags: apache-spark, mapr

I am running Spark 2.1 on Mapr 5.0

I am getting following exception while launching  Spark on local mode

My spark-default (Important configuration)

```
spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 0.13.1
spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars 
                          /opt/mapr/lib/maprfs-5.0.0-mapr.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/conf:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:

                          /opt/hadoopgpl/lib/hadoop-lzo.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0-mapr-1506.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.0-mapr-1506.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/lib/libprotodefs-5.0.0-mapr.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/lib/baseutils-5.0.0-mapr.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/guava-13.0.1.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/hadoop-common-2.7.0-mapr-1506.jar:
                          /opt/mapr/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar

spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes com.mysql.jdbc,org.postgresql,com.microsoft.sqlserver,oracle.jdbc,com.mapr.fs.shim.LibraryLoader,com.mapr.security.JNISecurity,com.mapr.fs.jni,com.mapr.fs.shim


java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/apache/spark/sql/hive/client/IsolatedClientLoader$$anon$1): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/mapr/fs/jni/MapRConstants"
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
... 104 more
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating   
'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
```

Please help me on that

Comment: Was it eventually solved? Can you update the thread with your remarks?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue.
When running my Spark job using spark-submit everything worked but running it locally reproduced the same problem.

Digging out into MapR community yielded this post: https://community.mapr.com/thread/21262-spark-todf-returns-linkage-error-duplicate-class-definition#comments

In addition you will notice that in your cluster in this file spark-defaults.conf there is the following config key: spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes

So, adding this key **spark.sql.hive.metastore.sharedPrefixes** in SparkConf fixed my problem.

Here is an explanation of this key:

> a comma separated list of class prefixes that should be loaded using
>   the classloader that is shared between Spark SQL and a specific
>   version of Hive. An example of classes that should be shared is JDBC
>   drivers that are needed to talk to the metastore. Other classes that
>   need to be shared are those that interact with classes that are
>   already shared. For example, custom appenders that are used by log4j.

You can read more about it in here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html